# Write a custom validation for year range using jquery or javascript

Tags: jquery, ruby, regex

I want to add a custom validation for one field which is nothing but the year range, and I have a one format for it. while submitting the form I need to validate that field. the format for year range is

`2012-2013` or `2010-2011, 2012-2013, 2013-2014` like this.

So I am trying with regular expression I have written following expression:
`^\d{4}-\d{4}$` but its not validating the `2010-2011, 2012-2013, 2013-2014` so I need to validate both secnario.

What I need to do for modify my regular expression which validate above examples.

Comment: fwiw I created this javascript lib to validate year ranges: https://github.com/jonschlinkert/is-valid-year. hope it's useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an optional group construct to validate both formats.

```
^\d{4}-\d{4}(?:, *\d{4}-\d{4})*$
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?:        # group, but do not capture (0 or more times):
  ,        #   ','
   *       #   ' ' (0 or more times)
  \d{4}    #   digits (0-9) (4 times)
  -        #   '-'
  \d{4}    #   digits (0-9) (4 times)
)*         # end of grouping
```